# Getting NaN when generating a percentage

Tags: double, nan, division

So here is my code:

```
            int var1 = serverList[i].webUp;
            int var2 = serverList[i].webUp + serverList[i].webDown;
            double ratio = (double)var1 / var2;
            ratio = ratio * 100.0;
            string percentage = string.Format("Up time is {0:P2}%", ratio);
```

Every time I run my application I keep getting NaN instead of a percent. `webUp` and `webDown` are both int, and I'm type casting to double when I do the division. Any ideas? I'm not dividing by 0, all values are greater than 0 and never in the negative. I keep getting `"Up time is NaN%"`

Comment: what happens when you add cast to (double) for var2?

Comment: I have also tried just converting ratio to string and just outputing that directly...still NaN.....

Comment: What are the values of `var1` and `var2`?  It sounds like `var2` has to be 0 to cause this.

Comment: sigh....indeed....i revamped my app's interface and changed the order of a few variables...both webup and webdown get fed the wrong values and became 0.... forgot all about the new order of variables. lol thank you Martin

Comment: I don't think you need to multiply by 100 (ratio = ratio * 100.0) as you are saving a percentage.See:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

1 equates to 100%